# No member 'presentViewController' when Authenticating Player

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I'm trying to log into GameCenter into my app. I get the error:

> Value of type 'GameScene' has no member 'presentViewController' when
>   trying to present the view controller.

My authentication function

```
func authPlayer(){
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {
        (view, error) in

        if view != nil {
            self.presentViewController(view!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            print(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What class does the `presentViewController` belong to? What class is `self` in your posted code? See the problem?

Comment: I can't import GKGameCenterController into my class because I get the error `Type 'GameScene' does not conform to protocol 'GKGameCenterControllerDelegate'`

Answer (score 0):

`self.presentViewController` only works if `self` is a subclass of UIViewController.

In addition, if `view` is a UIView and not a UIViewController, then:

```
self.presentViewController(view!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

won't work either unless `view` is poorly named and is really a UIViewController subclass.  This isn't GameKit specific.  The basics of the iOS UI hierarchy is:

```
App -> Key Window -> Root View Controller -> Child View Controller -> Root View
```

You can have many child view controllers, but each has only one child.  Every UIViewController has one or more `UIView`s, and those views can have one or many child views depending on its type and nature.

Comment: In your first sentence you need to replace "child" with "subclass".

Comment: How would I fix this then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291922/handling-game-center-authentication has a proper implementation of GKLocalPlayer authentication.